# How To Customise A DIV Element With CSS Coding

Tags: html, css, blogger

I would like help with two issues that I'm having with my blog header. The first problem is that I want the social media icons/links to have a far bit of distance - approximately 60px - from the word "BLANKESQUE". I would ideally want the social media icons to appear on the right side of the screen rather than alongside the word "BLANKESQUE".

The second problem is yet again with the social media icons. I would like there to be two different coloured icons for the same media platform. For example the #headersocial would display the grey coloured media icons but the #headersocial a:hover would display the same icon but in a black colour. I understand I would need two sets of media icons, one set that is grey and the other set black however I don't understand how I can code the html to achieve the look I want. The URL to my blog is as follows : http://www.blankesque.com

I have included the full header coding below:

```css
#customheader a {
    font-size: 55px;
    font-family: calibri;
    color: #777777;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: normal!important;
    letter-spacing: 0.25em;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#customheader {
    margin: 12% 0 2.5% -8%;
    float: left;
}
#customheader a:hover {
    color: #000000!important;
}
#headersocial {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    opacity: 0.6;
    filter: alpha(opacity=60);
}
#headersocial a {
    padding: 0px 25px;
}
#headersocial a:hover {
    text-decoration: none!important;
}
```

```html
<div id='customheader'>
    <a href='http://www.blankesque.com'>Blankesque</a>
    <div id='headersocial'> 
        <a href='https://www.pinterest.com/blankesque' target='_blank'><img height='35px' src='http://i1379.photobucket.com/albums/ah140/mynamesiram/Mobile%20Uploads/91F98FB1-242C-428E-A472-50F7D511C38E_zpsaiuhz6yb.gif' width='35px'/>
</a>
        <a href='https://www.twitter.com/itsblankesque' target='_blank'><img height='35px' src='http://i1379.photobucket.com/albums/ah140/mynamesiram/Mobile%20Uploads/923FF7F8-5AA7-4676-935F-2CB5FF465122_zpsmctqg100.gif' width='35px'/></a>
        <a href='http://www.bloglovin.com/people/aladyinwhite-8315551' target='_blank'><img height='35px' src='http://i1379.photobucket.com/albums/ah140/mynamesiram/Mobile%20Uploads/7CC1080E-1911-4D0B-B99F-55109C044D54_zps2ky5dfgt.gif' width='35px'/></a>
        <a href='https://instagram.com/itsblankesque' target='_blank'><img height='35px' src='http://i1379.photobucket.com/albums/ah140/mynamesiram/Mobile%20Uploads/C6567CDB-FB01-4F2D-A2FD-D0D875A30B80_zps5mgdqong.gif' width='35px'/></a>
        <a href='mailto: blankesque@hotmail.com' target='_blank'><img height='35px' src='http://i1379.photobucket.com/albums/ah140/mynamesiram/Mobile%20Uploads/55416E3D-525A-499B-8E7F-BEA34ED80146_zpss1svraqx.gif' width='35px'/></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

See the below given screenshot

[image]

To make your page look like this, first of all you have to change your CSS for `#customheader` as follows

```
#customheader {
    margin: 12% 0 2.5% 0%;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Next, to align the text `BLANKESQUE` stick to the left side, add `float:left` to 
`#customheader a`. So the new CSS for `#customheader a` would be as follows

```
#customheader a {
    font-size: 55px;
    font-family: calibri;
    color: #777777;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: normal!important;
    letter-spacing: 0.25em;
    text-decoration: none;
    float: left;
}
```

And, for the effect that you need on hover, I would suggest you to keep a transparent image, and then set the background color through CSS. Same way, you can change the background color on hover too. Would be the easiest way..

Comment: For the spacing, she might consider:

    `#customheader
    {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }`

(remove the float, nothing else is critical for the spacing) [link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Messing with floats to do this kind of thing has been the artform of css for a long time, but flex is a lot less prone to weird behavior in my experience.

Comment: This is just one of the number of solutions..please post your solution as a new answer..would be helpfull for others too..I think, the second problem is a bit opinion based.. @TrygveSkogsholm

Comment: Everything is an opinion. What matters is whether the opinion is based on logic and evidence. For instance, with flex applies to more than one element. To achieve the same effect with floats requires knowing how many elements there are and adding padding offsets.

floats take the element out of flow, they were meant for figures in text. Flex establishes a new definition for flow. They were meant for spacing things around in a box.